# How to obtain a dataset that contains only the date that represents the first of each month

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset like this :

```
+----------+
|        dt|
+----------+
|2019-08-08|
|2019-08-22|
|2019-08-23|
|2019-08-31|
|2019-08-29|
|2019-08-01|
|2019-08-04|
|2019-08-11|
|2019-08-15|
|2019-09-03|
|2019-08-27|
|2019-08-28|
|2019-08-06|
|2019-09-01|
|2019-08-07|
|2019-08-17|
|2019-09-04|
|2019-08-10|
|2019-08-12|
|2019-09-02|
+----------+
```

It's a dataset and I obtain like this :

```
val df_cra = getData(_spark, prefix + use_db, tb_cra)
  .where("to_date(dt, 'yyyy-MM-dd') >= to_date('" + recupDate + "', 'yyyy-MM-dd')")

val mois_usage = df_cra
  .groupBy("dt")
```

Now, I want to get a dataset (or list) from the first day of the month each time a month is present in my starting dataset.
For my example, I hope :

```
+----------+
|    result|
+----------+
|2019-08-01|
|2019-09-01|
+----------+
```

Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming dates is a list of strings in YYYY-MM-DD format, and you can use java.time, you can do:

```
import java.time._

dates.map(v => LocalDate.parse(v, format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE))
    .foldLeft(Set.empty[YearMonth])((yms, dt) => yms + YearMonth.from(dt))
    .map(_.atDay(1))
```

which gives a `Set[java.time.LocalDate]` of `Set(2019-08-01, 2019-09-01)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.

I try but I have a error so I try to convert my Dataset in a list of string like this :

val list_dt = df_date.select("dt").collect().map_(0)).toList

And after I try your code like this :

list_dt.map(v => LocalDate.parse(v, format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE))
  .foldleft(Set.empty[YearMonth] ((yms, dt) => yms + YearMonth.from(dt))
  .map(_.atDay(1))

And I have an error message "Cannot resolve reference parse with such signature"

Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think list_dt becomes a `List[Any]`, and parse needs a `String`, so try `list_dt.map(_.toString).map(v => LocalDate.parse(v, format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE))` and the rest of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

if you are operating on `Dataset[Row]` you can use spark sql, see example below:

```
df.groupBy(year('date),month('date)).agg(min('date).as("result")).show()
```

or

```
df.createTempView("df")
spark.sql("select min(date) as result from df group by year(date), month(date)").show()
```

```
    +----------+
    |    result|
    +----------+
    |2019-08-01|
    |2019-09-01|
    +----------+
```

Comment: Thank a lot, but I think the min() doesn't work because I want always the first day in the month (****-**-01) and maybe I don't have this value in my Dataset.
In my example, I don't have the 01 for September.